# Inclde special characters on token generation

Tags: django-rest-framework, token

I want to add/customize token generation that it should include special characters as well.

Is this possible?

This is for a django rest framework token auth app.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details? What tokens are we talking about here?

Comment: if I integrate token authentication on my api, is there a way to include special characters on the generated token? I noticed they are mostly chars and integers.